# Neo4j: shortest path starting at A, ending in B and passing through all nodes with label X

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to find the shortest path starting at A, ending in B and passing through all nodes with label marked as Delivery.

My dataset is as follows:
node a:Station 'depart Oakland'
node b:Station 'arrive Oakland'
node c:Delivery 'customer c'
node d:Delivery 'customer d'
node e:Delivery 'customer e'

Every node has a relationship with every other node based on the distance from each other (Oakland is the center, arrive and depart are just name, the lat/lon are the same)

I need to find the shortest (based on distance) leaving from Oakland and returning to Oakland passing through all the :Delivery nodes.

I tried the following code but it just gives me all the relationships I have. HELP

'''

```
MATCH (n) WHERE (n:Delivery = True) or (n.name = 'depart Oakland') or (n.name = 'arrive Oakland')
WITH collect(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as n
UNWIND nodes as m
WITH * WHERE id(n) < id(m)
MATCH path = allShortestPaths( (n)-[:TIME*..4]-(m)) 
RETURN path
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Is that just in neo4j browser?

Try to disable "connect result nodes in the config section of the left sidebar" that should only show you what you actually return.